# Bin Bash Script is Slow

Tags: bash, performance

I know nothing about this but have been tasked with investigating. Can anyone tell me why this would be slow? or offer any changes/alternatives?

```
#!/bin/bash

target="/Users/mariya/Desktop/Distribution"
echo “Target is something”
pushd "$target" > /dev/null

FILES="./*.pdf"
for f in $FILES
do
  # Remove spaces from file
  mv "$f" "${f//[[:space:]]}"
done

let count=0
for f in *
do
    echo "Now printing: "  $f
    lpr -single -o landscape -o media=Custom.8.5x11in -o scale=100 -o page-ranges=1 $f
    echo "Printing Complete"
    let count=count+1
done
popd
echo ""
echo "Total Printed: $count"
```

Comment: Which part is slow, the renaming loop or the printing loop?

Comment: how big is the dir?  `for f in *` might be big.  Also, how long does it take to do an `lpr`?  Maybe that could be your bottleneck.  I think you may need to provide some more timing information so that we can help you

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. Then you'll see each line as it's executing, so you should be able to see where it takes time.

Comment: note that your `mv` command may unintentionally overwrite existing files. eg. `god is now here.pdf` / `god is nowhere.pdf` --> `godisnowhere.pdf`